# urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: ftps

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftps

I am working on this simple program to connect

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.request as req
import ssl


req = urllib.request.Request('ftps://ftps-xyz.com')
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

I am trying to connect and open a FTPS website to be able to download some files but I get the error.

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: ftps
```

Didn't find many further info on this. Can anyone point me in the right direction. I am using Python 3.6 , Windows.
I am looking to understand what am I doing wrong and if there is an alternative way to implement this?

Comment: This error is pretty clear - urllib (at least in this configuration) doesn't support ftps.

Comment: I was hoping get some alternative approach suggested as well :)

Comment: Then you should say that in your question. It currently reads like you don't understand the error message.

Comment: Are you open to using different tools or programming languages other than python? Does this code need to operate with other code, or is this simply a means to download a bunch of files off an ftps server?

Comment: it is simply meant to download a bunch of files off an ftp server.

Comment: Have you considered using a ftp client like filezilla?

Comment: I want to implement a bunch of rules based on which the files will get downloaded. Filezilla download is manual unfortunately

Comment: @swalladge SFTP and FTPS are two different protocols. It's confusing and infuriating but so that's not a particularly suitable duplicate.

Comment: @tripleee oooh right TIL. thanks!